# Python SQLite Database Result has unwanted brackets and quotation marks

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am doing an assignment from Coursera Course "Using Databases with Python" and in one of the assignment I ran into this issue where the column of my database result returned has brackets and quotation marks around it. (It should return org as `iupui.edu` instead of my current result `['iupui.edu']`

Please refer to my code below:

```
import sqlite3
import re

conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if (len(fname) < 1): fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: '): continue
    pieces = line.split()
    email = pieces[1]
    org = str(re.findall('@(\S+)', email))
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org = ? ', (org,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (org, count)
                VALUES (?, 1)''', (org,))
    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count = count + 1 WHERE org = ?',
                    (org,))

conn.commit()

# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT org, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
    print(str(row[0]), row[1])

cur.close()
```

The mbox file is here: https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt
I have a feeling I shouldn't convert org to string class but I don't know what else to convert it to because
I would greatly appreciate your help as I've been trying to fix it for hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with how you're saving it:

```py
org = str(re.findall('@(\S+)', email))
```

Here, you find all email orgs, right? but how do you process them? Instead of taking the first value, you cast it into a string. Here's the problem. `findall` returns a list, even if there is only one result. This is what you can do:

```py
org = re.findall('@(\S+)', email)[0]
```

Now, `org` is still a string, but it no longer has brackets, as you are not casting a list to a string.